# Using MSXML to fetch data from website

Tags: vba

I am trying to use the following code to geocode a bunch of cities from this website: mygeoposition.com but there seems to be some sort of issue and the variable 'Lat' in the following code always returns empty:

```
Sub Code()

Dim IE As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Set IE = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

IE.Open "GET", "http://mygeoposition.com/?q=Chuo-ku, Osaka", False
IE.send

While IE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Wend

Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim htmlBody As MSHTML.htmlBody

Set HTMLDoc = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Set htmlBody = HTMLDoc.body

htmlBody.innerHTML = IE.responseText

Lat = HTMLDoc.getElementById("geodata-lat").innerHTML

IE.abort

End Sub
```

I have another code that uses the browser to do the same thing and it works fine with that but it gets quite slow. When I use this code with MSXML, it just doesn't work. Apologies I am a newbie with using VBA for data extraction from website. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The response contains no content in the geodata-lat element. It appears that client side code is getting that data so your response only is looking at the html that the server generated. I tried this out myself and this is the section of the response you are looking for. You can see it is empty:
[image: xmlhttp response]

If you try an element that has content (geodata-kml-button), it does pull in a value ("Download KML file"). Ignore the ByteArrayToString() call, that was just me testing:
[image]

If they don't have a real API then I don't think you can get your data this way.